# What does "hey them" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The context is that I bought some books from a seller in Instagram and after the transaction was completed (meaning they still need to be shipped) he told me:

> Your books are now in the hands of the shipper. Let me know when you hey them!

At first, I thought he was trying to say "Let me know when you get them!", but then he said:

> Hey them? Maybe when you get them.

And then I was pretty sure he meant exactly what he said. Sometimes when I post on Instagram, bragging about my books, I tag the bookseller in the post, but maybe I misunderstood the intention.

Do you think is that what he meant? This is the first time I see the use of "hey" as a verb (?).

Answer (score 2):

Look at your keyboard. H and G are right next to each other. T and Y are right next to each other. A and E are very close.

The seller meant to say "get them" but mistyped. Their phone autocorrected to "hey them."

Comment: ...and he was telling you (with a laughing emoticon) that that is what he must have meant.

Comment: Yeah. He was correcting himself in the second message. In a joking (self deprecating) manner.